# Generalised Tobit for clustered data (type 2?)

Tags: regression, clustering, estimation, stata, tobit-regression

I would like to make a Tobit estimation where my dependent variable is stadium attendance, but there are observations from 18 different stadiums (different capacities).
My thoughts are it may be type 2 tobit (not sure), but I dont know how to censore observations with different limits. I would like to implement this estimation in Stata program.

I found a source where authors do the same model as me and the table with estimators in their model is titled:
*Parameter estimates of the generalized Tobit models clustered for home teams*.

Here is a link to to the article I mentioned above:
[Pawlowski; Anders estimation - article](http://www.tim-pawlowski.de/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Pawlowski-T.-Anders-C.-2012.pdf)

Comment: Vote to leave open, since there is a question about different types of tobit model. The question *could* use a clean up, though.

Comment: You should give the reference in accessible form. You should cite cross-posting of similar material at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598161/stata-tobit-estimation-more-than-one-limitation That's perilously near closure but comments to date are still pertinent.

Comment: @NickCox is right, but I also agree that there is a potential statistical question which can be on-topic here. Note that [some forms](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/2132/7290) of cross-posting can be acceptable on SE. Just edit your Qs so that the post on [SO] is specific to the 'how to use Stata' aspect & this post is specific to the statistical questions, & explicitly note & link to them.

Comment: Thanks,
I made changes, to make topic more suitable to this forum and added a link to the article mentioned before.